# How do you call the largest unsigned item in a list?

Tags: mathematics

What is the clearest way to refer to -10 in the example vector *v*; *v* = (1, ⅔, -10)?  I initially was going to refer to it as the largest entry of 
*v* but don't want to run the risk of having the reader infer that I'm 
implying 1 (obviously, in this paragraph I'm talking about the 'largest' of a non-specific vector, so I can't refer to it as the third entry).

Here is the context:

> […] we use the convention of flipping the sign of ***P<sub>q</sub>*** so that
>   it's largest unsigned entry is always positive.

***P<sub>q</sub>*** is a matrix with many entries (some positive, some negative). 
It turns out that the only the magnitude of these entries matter in this 
application. Still, to compare two such matrices (say ***P<sub>q</sub>*** and ***P<sub>qʹ</sub>***), we need to impose a sign convention.

Comment: The entry of *v* with the smallest value, perhaps? Can you give us some context, such as the intended audience?

Comment: I'm not a math guy, but do you mean "largest in absolute value (in modulus)"? Please give a context on what is considered to be a "largest entry" in a vector.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technical mathematical language, not English usage.

Comment: @ColinFine the paper is written in english though.

Comment: Well, if only magnitude matters, then you can stick with "largest entry in absolute value (in modulus\in magnitude), I don't think you can make it more compact, though I might be mistaken.

Comment: @Vilmar, can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: You should ask technical experts (in English) about this, most likely over in mathematics.SE

Comment: Hi, I'm just going through posts which have "How do you call....?" titles. Would you mind editing it to "What do you call the ....?" See: [“How do we call (something) in English?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150325/how-do-we-call-something-in-english) Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could refer to *the extreme value* or *an extreme value*.    For example, “We use the convention of flipping the sign of P_q so that its extreme entry is positive.”

Using *largest-magnitude* as an adjective is also a possibility: “We adjust the sign of P_q such that its largest-magnitude entry is positive.”

Similarly, *entry of largest magnitude* is a possibility: “We adjust the sign of P_q such that its entry of largest magnitude is positive.”

I regard  “largest entry in magnitude” as a wrong or unnatural phrase.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that only absolute value matters when determining the largest entry in a vector, so to make it clear for the audience what a "largest" entry is, you can elaborate:

> Largest entry in absolute value
>
> Largest entry in modulus
>
> Largest entry in magnitude

Comment: I'd use '... entry with the largest absolute value'.

Comment: "Absolute value " is my answer too.

Comment: I'm a mathematician and I'd just write: largest (absolute) value because anyone reading the paper would understand.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps *maximum of min and max* Or *maximum absolute value*. Depends on the intended audiences.

Comment: Your first sentence sounds like the way Yoda might explain it.